# Invisible robot model in Rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic, xacro, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new to rviz and I encountered a problem while i was trying to run project from this [repo](https://github.com/richardw05/mybot_ws.git) . When im working on Gazebo i can see a whole model of the robot but when i try to do the same on Rviz i can see only laser scanner model.

[image: Robot in Gazebo]

[image: Robot in Rviz]

Full code is available [HERE](https://github.com/richardw05/mybot_ws).
The only thing I've changed is when i was trying to run for example gazebo i had errors which were saying that something is wrong with mybot.xacro, I've changed the type of point separated values were typed from

```
 <box size=".4 .2 .1"/>
```

to

```
<box size="0.4 0.2 0.1"/>
```

end everything work fine except the thing i cant see the model in Rviz.

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.05 LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337223/invisible-robot-model-in-rviz./) by [asbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/49167/asbird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-11-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-09**:
Additionally: please attach your screenshots directly to the question, instead of linking to an off-site image host. That way we keep this post self-contained.

I've given you sufficient karma for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but as you mention your robot model is invisible in RViz, perhaps this is #q272692. Worth checking.

---

Edit:

> was about to say that this doesn't work but then I've typed first source devel/setup.bash and then export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" - finally it worked !

you'll probably want to add that line to your `.bashrc` to avoid having to retype it every time.

Note that this will change the way your OS represents/encodes/decodes floating point nrs though.

Finally: according to [ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/45 - comment](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/45#issuecomment-551877532) the fixed version of `urdfdom_headers` should finally be released as an update to Ubuntu Bionic.

So you should not need to override `LC_NUMERIC` any more in the near future -- after installing that update.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/49167/asbird/) on 2019-11-09**:
I was about to say that this doesn't work but then I've typed first source devel/setup.bash and then export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" - finally it worked ! Thank you very much @gvdhoorn